# `git stash create` does not return a hash

Tags: git, git-bash, git-stash, git-hash

Example (bash):

```
> cd ~/repo1
> git stash create
```

Clearly something is wrong, maybe there is already something *stashed*?

```
> git stash drop
No stash entries found
```

Maybe there is something wrong with git, pick a random other *repository* and *rerun*:

```
> cd ~/repo2
> git stash create
f6fed634ce4de28d8696de39f6a338df8edef59c
```

What's going on here?

Comment: That's not really a MWE cause `~/repo1` doesn't exist on my system. What did you do leading up to this? Maybe you added an alias to `stash` in the repo's gitconfig? Try `git help stash`. BTW what shell are you using?

Comment: quite right, @wjandrea, OP is corrected

Comment: Is that Bash? `cd(...)` is invalid syntax. Maybe you're using a different version or have some feature turned on?

Comment: Thanks, that's a typo, had been writing some Julia right before I updated the post to add cd's, to make the example more cohesive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's nothing to stash, there's no unstaged or staged changes, it won't make a commit object.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   this
$ git stash create
a42c068d4b8139a6d572ad04e77f1bd0057b3408

$ git restore this
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git stash create
$
```